# Como calcular valores dentro de arrays?

Tags: javascript

Estou com o seguinte algoritmo para efetuar o cálculo de uma calculadora polonesa reversa.

```
function  pilhaNumeroVisor() {
  var pilha = [] ;
  var num = document.calcform.visor.value;
  if(num != "" ) {
    pilha.push(num);
    document.calcform.visor.value = "" ;
  }
  if (num == "" ) {
    resultado = pilha[0] + pilha[1];
    document.calcform.visor.value = resultado;

  } 
}
```

O que era para retornar num `input` o resultado da soma, retorna `NaN`.
Alguém pode me ajudar?
Desde já agradeço atenção!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sempre vai dar `NaN` porque você está declarando a array dentro da função; logo, cada vez que a função é chamada, a array será vazia porque é redeclarada.

Outro ponto é: caso você tente somar os dois primeiros índices da array e um deles não existir, irá resultar em `NaN` também.

Você pode usar o método [.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) para ir somando os elementos da array à medida que vai adicionando valores.

Veja como ficaria (comentários explicativos no código):

```js
// declara a array fora da função
var pilha = [];

function  pilhaNumeroVisor() {

   // declara a variável "resultado"
   var resultado;
   var num = document.calcform.visor.value;

   if(num != "" ) {
      
      // adiciona o número na array em tipo "number"
      pilha.push(Number(num));
      document.calcform.visor.value = "" ;
   }

   if(num == "" ) {

      if(pilha.length){
         // altera a variável somando os valores
         resultado = pilha.reduce(function(a,b){
            return a + b;
         });
      }

      // o visor só vai receber valor se resultado for válido
      document.calcform.visor.value = resultado || '';
   } 
   
}
```

```html
<form name="calcform">
   <input type="text" name="visor">
   <button type="button" onClick="pilhaNumeroVisor()">OK</button>
</form>
```

Agora, você pode também usar este código mais enxuto:

```
var pilha = [];

function pilhaNumeroVisor(){

   var resultado,
   vis = document.calcform.visor,
   num = vis.value;

   if(num){
      pilha.push(Number(num));
      vis.value = "";
   }else if(pilha.length){
      resultado = pilha.reduce(function(a,b){
         return a + b;
      });
   } 
   vis.value = resultado || '';
}
```

Comment: Sam muito obrigado pela resposta! Me ajudou muito! Mas saberia como eu faria para operar todos os dados que estão dentro da array?

Comment: Como assim? Essa array vai ter no máximo dois números que irão se somar. Depois ela é esvaziada e assim por diante.

Comment: A operação dele é em dois dados coletados da array. Mas pelo IF sempre que o usuário inserir mais número a array vai armazenar. Então quero fazer a mesma operação só que, vamos supor, se a array tiver 4 números? Não sei se é possível! Por isso que pergunto.

Comment: Então peraí: vc quer ir armazenando os números? Dá pra ir armazenando sim. Depois vc quer somar tudo como resultado?

Comment: Sim isso mesmo!

Comment: Cara agora não fundou. Ele não está executando. Tentei ver novas formas de fazer o reduce e não consegui.

Comment: Antes da sua última função deu cerro pois apenas copiei e colei. A lógica está correta. Mas não sei por que não funfou esta segunda.

Comment: Ok. Muito obg pelo caminho até aqui! Já ajudou muito!

Comment: Cara descobri o problema funfou mesmo! Vlw!

Comment: Sam surgiu um bug. Essa array vai fica sem com os valores que o usuário armazenou. E possível zera essa array logo após o resultado ser apresentado no visor?

Comment: É só colocar `pilha = [];` após dar um valor à variável `resultado`, ou seja, após `resultado = pilha.reduce(function(a,b){
         return a + b;
      });`